# How to use one db to run the django service and other to fetch data

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

i have an existing application data base from which my web site should only fetch the data according to user input. Added database details in the `settings.py` file and I tried `python manage.py integratedb` and get the all the 300+ tables came off to my `models.py` file. I was never able to do `python manage.py runserver` it threw a million errors. Now i found a work around but i need your opinion on this.

I added the default server into the `settings.py` and using it i was able to run the server.  `settings.py` looks like this.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        },
    'user': {   
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME'  : 'test',
        'USER'  : 'testuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'readonly',
        'HOST'  : '10.20.30.40',
        'PORT'  : '5446',
    }
}
```

Now can i access the `user db` to fetch data from my form? for example

`views.py` looks like this

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from .models import TestCases
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt


# Create your views here.

@csrf_exempt
def index(request):
    posts = TestCases.objects.all()[:10]
    return render_to_response('index.html',{'posts':posts})
```

where `TestCases` is a class name from the `models.py` file.

Now when i click the button to retrieve data i get "no such table: test_cases"

```
models.py looks like


class TestCases(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    clientid = models.ForeignKey(Clients, db_column='clientid')
    projectid = models.ForeignKey(Projects, db_column='projectid')


    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'test_cases'
```

what am i doing wrong to get the data from the user input. please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Queryset `.using()` method

I guess Django is going for the default database.

Try this:

```
@csrf_exempt
def index(request):
    posts = TestCases.objects.using('user').all()[:10]
    return render_to_response('index.html',{'posts':posts})
```

When you set `using` to your queryset, you can specify which database django is going to query.

More information in [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database-for-a-queryset)

#### A better approach, so you don't have to manually set it to all your queries.

You can manually add it to all your queries, or you can create a custom manager to your objects and force it to use a specific database for objects.

Ex:

```
# this will override the default queryset for objects that use this Manager
class UserDatabaseManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().using('user')


class MyModel(models.Models):
    objects = UserDatabaseManager()
```

Then, when you use `MyModel`, you can query as usually and Django will use the `user` db for default just for models that have `objects = UserDatabaseManager()`.

Keep in mind that this is just a simple use of the Manager, you can have multiple managers and do a lot of cool stuff.

Take a look at the [Django Managers docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/)

Comment: working smooth as butter. Can you tell me if there any limitation i'll face using this strategy?

Comment: It can slow down refactors in the future. I had to use it, but i made a custom manager for my objects, i'll explain it, just gimme a second.

Comment: That's so cool. Thanks for looking into this. really appreciate your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to do:

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

to store your models to `models.py`

By default, inspectdb creates unmanaged models. That is, managed = False in the model’s Meta class tells Django not to manage each table’s creation, modification, and deletion, if you do want to allow Django to manage the table’s lifecycle, you’ll need to change the managed option above to True (or simply remove it because True is its default value).

Next, run the migrate command to install any extra needed database

```
python manage.py migrate
```

[integrating docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/)